# Event log table (not sure if needed) - Best practice

Tags: mysql, database, events, database-design

I'm building a small subscription site where I'd like to log a few things including the following:

```
User creation - When
Logged in history - When + IP
User phase 1 (complete profile) - When
User phase 2 (complete extra info) - When
Edit Info - When + What changed + Who made the changes (admin/mod/user)
Etc
```

I am currently tracking a few of the above events (each one got the info needed in their own table, for example registration date) but I am wondering if I should create a new Events Log Table to track everything or just the pieces missing (that might create a small chaos..).

What would be the best practice for such a problem?

I am sorry if my question is not very clear..

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking of an audit log. Some apps need this, some don't. You would know better than anyone here whether you need it. Ask yourself: when would you query this event log? What questions would you answer using the event log? Are those questions important, or are you just supposing they *might* come up? Read about the software design principle of [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) — You Aren't Gonna Need It.

Comment: Even if you do need an audit log, then you have to ask yourself: Does it need to be in a database? Or can it just be a text log file you append to? The answer depends on what types of queries you need to do against the audit log, and how frequently. Consider using a non-SQL technology that specializes in logging, like [LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) or [GrayLog](https://www.graylog.org).

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for the answer! These changes where asked by the ones who are using the site. They'd like to track user changes and admins/mods actions. This event log will only be called from within the admin panel by a couple of users and I was thinking that maybe if it was everything written in a single table it would be better to manage. I was thinking of showing a historic based events log (one for the last x events and one based on y user/mod/etc).

Comment: So instead of requesting X tables etc etc I could do everything with a single one. Maybe my thinking is wrong though :/

Comment: I think it's common to use one table, with a JSON column to contain a semi-structured record of what happened in the event. But add a column to the table for each attribute you want to be searchable. For example the datetime of the event. Or the userid.